# How to compare/match two comma separated values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have two comma separated values like

> s1("45,34,32,11")
>
> s2("34,10,49,45")

What I need is when query run it will check for matching like that.

Pick 45 `(first number from s1)` & compare it with other series `(s2)` i.e `"34,10,49,45"` one by one & then pick second number from `(s1)` & again compare it with all the series items in `(s2)`, & so on...

Can any body help me on this in `MySQL`

**What I have tried**

```
Select * from `table` where s1 IN (s2)
```

Comment: why you want to compare values?

Comment: I need to compare it & get the result on matching through query.

Comment: If A sets of value matches B sets of value then you want to query for matched search

Comment: Yes, I have tried "IN", it works fine but only return if first element is matched, so it didn't query for other matching elements.

Comment: I don't believe that mysql has such operators and also Mysql don't have arrays so that we can compare with..

Comment: If you are querying through PHP or any other language then there are easy way to do it..

Comment: yes I am querying using PHP

Answer (score 1):

Using `FIND_IN_SET`

Consider column name is `category`

```
FIND_IN_SET('45', category) OR FIND_IN_SET('34', category) OR FIND_IN_SET('32', category) OR FIND_IN_SET('11', category)
```

Comment: Consider s1 array populate dynamically then how your solution possible?

Comment: I provided only the solution to the problem. In case of dynamic array, you can loop it in `PHP` and prepare a query part. Then concatenate it with main query.